# Reverse proxy using nginx tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, nginx, proxy

I am trying to understand how to use reverse proxy using nginx to my tomcat web server. I have created a spring boot web application running in its embedded tomcat server. Now, I downloaded Nginx and was able to get it up and running.

```
Default nginx page - `http://localhost:8090/`

Tomcat application is running at -`http://localhost:8080/`
```

Now, what I want is when I type the following address - `http://localhost:8090/index` - nginx should be able to redirect it to tomcat's `http://localhost:8080/home` 
Basically I want to be able to configure nginx to redirect it to tomcat.

This is my Nginx config file -

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8090;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location = /test.html {
            root    html;
        }
        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

I am running it on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 8090;
    location /index {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/home;
    }
}
```

However, it's unclear why you'd want to redirect from "/index" to "/home", or run nginx on port 8090, for that matter -- you'd usually go for port 80 for nginx.

A more common approach would be:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location /spring/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/home/;
    }
}
```